# how to convert dict to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert the dict,

```
{'IBM': Date
 2014-01-02         NaN
 2014-01-03    0.006004
 2014-01-06   -0.003426
 2014-01-07    0.019908
 2014-01-08   -0.009134
 2014-01-09   -0.003183
 2014-01-10   -0.000606
 Freq: B, Name: IBM, dtype: float64, 'MSFT': Date
 2014-01-02         NaN
 2014-01-03   -0.006683
 2014-01-06   -0.021026
 2014-01-07    0.007732
 2014-01-08   -0.017903
 2014-01-09   -0.006366
 2014-01-10    0.014269
 Freq: B, Name: MSFT, dtype: float64, 'ORCL': Date......
```

to the following dataframe,

```
Date         IBM    MSFT
1/2/2014    NaN          NaN
1/3/2014    0.006004    -0.006683
1/6/2014    -0.003426   -0.021026
1/7/2014    0.019908    0.007732
1/8/2014    -0.009134   -0.017903
1/9/2014    -0.003183   -0.006366
1/10/2014   -0.000606   0.014269
```

Comment: What you show is not a valid representation of a Python `dict`.  Can you clarify what the keys and values of that dict are?

Comment: I used the following code,'import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.data import DataReader

symbols_list = ['ORCL', 'TSLA', 'IBM','YELP', 'MSFT']
d = {}
for ticker in symbols_list:
    d[ticker] = DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", '2014-01-01','2014-01-10')
pan = pd.Panel(d)
df1 = pan.minor_xs('Adj Close')

n = []
for i in df1.columns:
    n.append(i)

returnsData={}
for tiker in n:
    prices=df1[tiker]
    returnsData[tiker]=prices/prices.shift(1)-1
'

Comment: You can just do ``pd.DataFrame(your_dict)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple, pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html